# Centering multiple input elements with equal space in CSS

Tags: css, forms, radio-button

I've got some radio buttons with their text. How can I center all this stuff, so that the first button is the same 'margin-left' as the 'margin-right' of last letter of the P of the last INPUT?

**HTML**

```
<div class='someClass'>
    <input type='radio' name='someName'>example
    <input type='radio' name='someName'>other text
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.someClass{
    width:400px}

.someClass input{
    float:left}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Inputs are self-closing and can't have children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `display: inline-block` for elements to put theme together in a line, still keep wide box model properties like margin, padding, etc for them:

```css
.someClass{
  text-align: center;
}
.someClass .inputs{
  display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<div class='someClass'>
    <p class="inputs"><input type='radio' name='someName'>example</p>
    <p class="inputs"><input type='radio' name='someName'>other text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: the thing is - i need it as in `display:flex; justify-content:center`. Can that happen with tables?

Comment: yes, but that is as in `justify-content:space-around`

Comment: And that is not the desired output? If not, what is exactly the desired output? please provide some more details or an screenshot if possible

Comment: i need the two inputs with no space between them, still centered

Comment: just one last - can we get the same result using P?

Comment: Yes! just give it a try. the important thing is setting `inline-block` value for `display` property, not the element itself

Answer (score 0):

First, you markup is invalid. Inputs are void elements, so they can't have any content.

An then, to do the centering, you may try flexbox's `justify-content: center`.

```css
.someClass {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='someClass'>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' name='someName' />
    example
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type='radio' name='someName' />
    other text
  </label>
</div>
```